# Eclipse debugger error in final launch sequence

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, debugging

For months I've been running Eclipse Juno with CDT to debug my C++ code.  Up to a couple weeks ago (when I last tried to debug) everything was working fine.  Recently I upgraded my eclipse juno installation to the latest. Building and executing the code in eclipse works fine.  But now when I try to launch the eclipse debugger I get the following error:

Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-break-insert -t -f main
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot access memory at address 0xfffe9900
Cannot access memory at address 0xfffe9900

I've tried searching online for this error without success.  I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to address this.

My environment:

I'm running on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
My xcode version is: Version 8.0 (8A218a) (with Command line tools installed)

My Eclipse info is:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

CDT Version: 8.6.0.201502131403

My Eclipse CDT Tool chain Editor looks like:
Current toolchain: MacOSX GCC
Current builder: Gnu Make Builder

I'm running with GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.2
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0"

I'm guessing that there is some sort of gdb version issue.  I'm using whatever gdb version that xcode dropped into /usr/local/bin/

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks, Mike
.
.
.
.
.

Ok.  So I ran gdb from the command line and it's behaving a little strangely. If I set a breakpoint anywhere within the main program it results in an error, such as,  Cannot access memory at address 0xfffe9900.   If instead I set a breakpoint in a function in an external file then run it goes to the proper breakpoint and accepts step, print, continue,....  For some reason I cannot set break points in main without getting the error, Cannot access memory at address 0x.............      I'm compiling all the codes (including my main) with the -g option.   BTW the error, Cannot access memory at address 0x......... is the same as what I'm getting from eclipse debugger.  So it looks like it cannot access the main code memory for whatever reason.  I haven't changed my make file either.  The only things that changed possibly is gcc and gdb.

Comment: the best way would be to perform a console-only test using only gdb and your executable, and the above command. Then you could [edit] your question with gdb only (no eclipse): more people would be able to answer.

Comment: I ran gdb from the command line and the results are shown above.  After  Thanks Mike

Comment: BTW, Im running g++ as              $g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: can you try `-gdwarf-2` instead of `-g` ?

Comment: I just tried it.  Both on the command line and eclipse.  Same result, Cannot access memory at address 0xfffe9900.   No other info.

Comment: can you do: `gdb yourapplication` then `break main` and then `info break` and show the results?

Comment: @Jean-Francois Sorry for the delay..  I just tried what you suggested and get the following,   >gdb bin/DFMS_PDS_L2_to_L3... After the GDB preamble I get to the    gdb> break main  that results in the usual "Cannot access memory at address 0xfffe9900" .  I then issue  gdb>info break  with the results, "No breakpoints or watchpoints.'.

Comment: At this point it looks like the source image of the main is not being loaded to memory in gdb.  All other sources are!!  Weird.  I'm not sure why this would be the case.  I can set breakpoints in any of the other functions and classes I've written but not main!?!?!?

Comment: a workaround to try would be to create an empty main and immediately call an auxiliary main. try that and test if you can put a breakpoint in the aux_main in the other file that way (maybe the linker is treating the main differently, triggering a bug)

Comment: At this point it looks like the source image of the main is not being loaded to memory in gdb.  All other sources are!!  Weird.  I can set breakpoints in any of the other functions and classes I've written but not main!?!?!?  I can run the program in gdb after setting breakpoints in other classes/functions and it breaks at the proper place but if I try to set breakpoints anywhere in main it gives me the access error.

Comment: BTW,  I set up a simple "Hello World" cpp program that calls a function in a separate file.  This example works fine.  Breaks are successfully set in main and the external function.  So it must be something within my project main but I haven't changed anything in it since upgrading gcc and gdb.  Before the upgrade gdb worked fine.  Very weird.  Maybe something in my main is no longer accepted or is mangled by the new gcc or gdb?

Comment: Just read your latest comment.  How do you call an aux_main from a main?   Isn't that equivalent to calling a function from main.  I thought you can't have more than one main in a cpp project.

Comment: just rename your current main into aux_main, and create a file containing main which callls aux_main. But that's a nasty workaround. Have you tried dumping the symbols of your executable (nm command)? or generate the mapfile at link phase?

Comment: I tried running nm on the file containing main.  Here's a snippet,  00000000001508bc S _iicnt
00000000001504a8 S _infNanErr
00000000001500ec S _intMode
000000000015083c S _isNewPDS
0000000000036ec0 D _isRecentGCUavailable
000000000014fc58 S _l3Log
00000000000001f0 T _main          The only thing that stands out to me is that main's address is a much earlier address than the typical others.  Not sure if this is significant or just the main being set early in the sandbox memory.